# Configuration Hadoop Capacity Scheduler for SAP HANA

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, hana

Firstly, I would like to ask about the function of Hadoop Capacity Scheduler in SAP HANA? Why SAP Hana need that? Because I just found the steps to "create a dedicated YARN queue for `TempletonControllerJobs`" in the SAP Help Page when I try to make hadoop as a cold storage butI don't know how to make a `templetoncontrollerjob`. Can anyone please help me to create a `TempletonControllerJobs` for SAP Hana?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuration Hadoop Capacity Scheduler For SAP 4 HANA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175106/configuration-hadoop-capacity-scheduler-for-sap-4-hana)

Comment: thankyou for replying, but its a same question